# how to get list of cities from a country knowing a city in that country in Django

Tags: django

I have 3 models for country, province ('state'), and city. Suppose i have 3 countries USA, Canada, and England. In addition, assume the user has selected the city of Orlando ( I got this city through  a form). Now, how can I get all cities in USA (assume there are limited amount of cities from USA in data base) in a dropdown menu. here are the models:

```
# country model
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

# province model
class Province(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)
# city model
class City(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)
```

I have tried the following code in view function:

```
def search(request):

    template = 'path/to/template.html'
    #get the name of the city
    query_c = request.GET.get('qc') 
    # get the country of this city
    p_c = Country.objects.filter(province__city__name__iexact=query_c)
    print(p_c)
    # get a list of cities belong to this country
    cities_in_post_city = 
    City.objects.filter(province__country__name=p_c)

    context={

    'all_p_cities': cities_in_post_city,

    }

    return render(request, template, context )
```

I need a list of all cities belong to the same country knowing only a city name. I do not care which city belong to which state. I tried to query the country of the known city. and then find all cities belong to this country. 
What I got is an empty query set. Any help or suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may query with the City model:

```
p_c = Country.objects.filter(province__city__name__iexact=query_c)
cities_in_post_city = City.objects.filter(province__country__in=p_c)
#cities_in_post_city = City.objects.filter(province__country__id__in=p_c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query City model like

```
cities = City.objects.filter(province__country__name=country_name)
```

where country_name is the name of the country where you want
Else if you have the country object then you can query like

```
cities = City.objects.filter(province__country=country)
```

By this you will get all the cities related to that specific country